# Cutting a 3D point cloud by a random surface by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3D point cloud in a cube with a specified side length, filled with particles at totally random positions. Also, I have a surface that has the same side length as the cube, but with random values of Z for each X and Y, which makes it a random rough surface. All of these data are in my access in XYZ format.

What I want to do is to delete the particles in the cube that stands above that rough surface.

The following generates a simple configuration of the problem:

```
samples = 1000;

%data extrema
l = -2; h = 2;
zl = 0; zh = 5;

%The point cloud
xC = random('Uniform',l,h,[samples,1]);
yC = random('Uniform',l,h,[samples,1]);
zC = random('Uniform',zl,zh,[samples,1]);

scatter3(xC,yC,zC,1);

% # grid points
gp = 20;

% grid costruction
xS = linspace(l,h,gp);
yS = linspace(l,h,gp);
[xS,yS] = meshgrid(xS,yS);
xS = xS(:);
yS = yS(:);

% random rough surface
zS = random('Uniform',zl+2,zh-2,[length(xS),1]);

hold on
scatter3(xS,yS,zS);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Deleting" means setting to 0? You will need to define a Z value for that (X,Y) pair. What if you just substract the Surface Z values from the cloud Z values (`zC-zS`)? Then values that remain positive are above the surface and negative values are below the surface

Comment: By "deleting" I mean removing the point from the cloud. And, that subtract method would work perfectly if I could manage how to compare the XY of the randomly distributed cloud with the regularly distributed surface; however, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You have to interpolate the (X,Y) coordinates to match the nearest coordinate in the surface. Take a look at that: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html#bs5vl1n

Comment: Thanks @BlackAdder. Now, using the "interp2", I estimate the position of the surface at the XY of each point, and compare it with the Z of the point. The code goes over all point one-by-one, so, for a large system it might be slow, but it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, I could solve the problem:

```
%% THE PROBLEM
samples = 1000;

% data extrema
l = -2; h = 2;
zl = 0; zh = 5;

% the point cloud
xC = random('Uniform',l,h,[samples,1]);
yC = random('Uniform',l,h,[samples,1]);
zC = random('Uniform',zl,zh,[samples,1]);

scatter3(xC,yC,zC,1);

% # grid points
gp = 20;

% sample grid costruction
xS = linspace(l,h,gp);
yS = linspace(l,h,gp);
[xSm,ySm] = meshgrid(xS,yS);
zSm = random('Uniform',zl+2,zh-2,[length(xS),length(yS)]);
xS = xSm(:);
yS = ySm(:);
zS = zSm(:);
hold on
scatter3(xS,yS,zS);

%% THE SOLUTION
% estimation of the zS for XY of each point
for i = samples:-1:1
    x_t = xC(i);
    y_t = yC(i);
    Zq = interp2(xSm,ySm,zSm,x_t,y_t,'linear');

    % delete the point if it is located above the surface
    if zC(i)>Zq
        xC(i) = [];
        yC(i) = [];
        zC(i) = [];
    end
end
scatter3(xC,yC,zC,30,'b');
```

Comment: You should be able to interpolate all the points without a `for` loop. And then remove all unwanted points at once. Otherwise using loops it will be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: I am using a very large system, sometimes more than a million particle in the cloud, and the way I figured out to do it without using loops resulted in memory error.